# How to query min( created_at ) in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

- I have about 70 of rows/items in my database.
- Everyday I inserted 10 rows so that will make 70 for the whole week, and rotate and delete the oldest one so on and so forth as I go ...
- Now I want to display them, NOT all, but **only the 10 of them** which is the one that are is the most updated ! which is the minimum of created_at.

How to write a where clause to query that ?

`Inventory::where(min(created_at))->get()` // doesn't work !

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know laravel, but you should sort the results by created_at ASC and limit the rezult set to 10

Comment: @Bogdan.Nourescu : That could be a solution, but no. ... I want to grab those 10 and that's it, and no need to worry about hiding/ limiting any results.

Comment: @kula It wont as you will only get a single result in your process, look at lukasgieter's answer and that will give you the results you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the newest 10 rows:

```
$result = Inventory::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

And this the oldest 10 rows:

```
$result = Inventory::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->take(10)->get();
```

---

To use `MIN()` you would need a subquery that first get's the lowest `created_at` and then use that in your where statement. Since you know that you always insert 10 rows ordering and limiting is the easiest way.

#### Edit

If you can't depend on the 10 rows per date you can use `MIN` like this:

```
$result = Inventory::where('created_at', function($q){
   $q->selectRaw('MIN(created_at)')
     ->from('inventories');
})->get();
```

Comment: I agree with you completely, but what if I want to grab all the min(created_at) , so that way I don't have to limit to 10, plus in the future who know maybe Monday, it inserted only 7, and Friday it inserted 12 thing like that you know, so min(created_at) will be the safest way for me. Can you help me a little bit more ? Thanks a head. :D

Comment: I've updated the answer. However I didn't test it... Let me know if it works

Comment: It doesn't break the view, so far so good, but my real data is about 9670, and your code is only grab 96 of them. It's so wired ! In the mean time, I am looking at them again right now, but if you notice anything before me please let me know.

Comment: If you want the latest ones you need to use `MAX(created_at)` just in case that's the problem...

Comment: I tried that and I got 95 rather than 96, what happened to the other 8000 ? Wonder ?

Comment: Hmm. So let me get that straight. You have over 8000 rows that have exactly the same `created_at` timestamp? not just the same day but the same time?

Comment: Then get the SQL query: `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` and 1) post it here  2) try to run it in some other db tool

Comment: Not I got this `select * from `inventories` where `created_at` = (select MAX(created_at) from `inventories`)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71096/discussion-between-kula-and-lukasgeiter).